# Firebug doesn't trap ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, firebug

Given the following:

```
var str = "apples";
try {eval(str)}
catch(e) {document.write('BAD CODE: '+e.name + ': '+e.message)}
```

Code works fine, the error message is printed out correctly, however, when run under Firebug, execution halts and Firebug pops up and says 'apples is not defined'. THIS SHOULD NOT HAPPEN, as the error is bracketed within a try-catch macro.

Try-catch properly catches other errors, such as TypeError and SyntaxError, and prevents them from popping up in Firebug. However, it doesn't trap ReferenceError.

All other browsers correctly trap ReferenceError.

Question: why does try-catch fail to trap this error? Is this an actual bug in Firebug?

Comment: The title of your question is "Firefox doesn't trap ReferenceError", but it seems like it's supposed to be "*Firebug* doesn't trap ReferenceError"?

Comment: Thanks ruakh, I changed the question title

Comment: FF10.0.2 FB1.9.1 - everything works ok.